# GLxx packages in org.lwjgl.opengl

Tags: lwjgl

The package `org.lwjgl.opengl` contains a whole bunch of packages named from `GL11` to `GL44` - one for every version from OpenGL 1.1 to OpenGL 4.4.

What exactly does this mean? Does each of these packages contain a separate, working version of OpenGL, or does each package contain only items that were introduced in that version? How do I figure out what things are where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly looks like each class contains only the newly added values/methods. For example the [GL44 class](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL44.html) contains only a fairly small set of entry points matching new features added in OpenGL 4.4.

Adding a new interface for each version does have advantages:

- Existing interfaces are not modified. It is mostly desirable not to modify interfaces once they were publicly exposed. Having various versions of the same interface can be problematic.
- It makes it easier for programmers to target a specific OpenGL version, because you can tell which version each entry point is supported in based on the class name.

The downside is that you need to know (or look up) the version where each call was introduced, so that you know which class to use for the call.

I'm surprised that they did not establish an inheritance hierarchy between the classes. That would seem to give the best of both worlds:

- Existing class interfaces are not modified when new versions are introduced.
- Easy for programmers to target a specific maximum version by using that class.
- No need for programmers to take into account the specific version where a call was introduced, as long as it's included in their target version.

This also make conceptual sense, because each version is an extension of the previous version, which matches a subclass relationship. The OpenGL ES Java bindings in Android uses this approach. `GLES30` derives from `GLES20`. Therefore, if you're targeting ES 3.0, you can call all the entry points on `GLES30`, even the ones that were already present in ES 2.0.